# Weird spacing below single lined h3

Tags: html, css, spacing

My `<h3>` elements have some weird white space when it's on one line. When it's more than one lines, there's no spacing. Image attached.

[image: h3 on one line]

[image: h3 in two lines]

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #519B96;
  line-height: 1!important;
  margin: 0 0px 25px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 30px!important;
  margin: 40px 0 -10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.teal {
  color: #519B96!important;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="teal">«Les Lettres persanes» (1721)</h3>
<p class="p1">
  “Les Lettres persanes”, roman qu’il publie dans l’anonymat à Amsterdam en 1721
</p>
```

Comment: Please attach html & css that demonstrate your problem.

Comment: can you add your html and css minimal code snippet

Comment: Ok here it is 

HTML

<h3 class="teal">«Les Lettres persanes» (1721)</h3>

<p class="p1">“Les Lettres persanes”, roman qu’il publie dans l’anonymat à Amsterdam en 1721</p">

CSS

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: #519B96;
  line-height: 1!important;
  margin: 0 0px 25px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 30px!important;
  margin: 40px 0 -10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.teal {
color: #519B96!important;
}

Comment: Do you still get that spacing with a different font?

Comment: Yes, same problem with different font.

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```css
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { 
            color: #519B96; 
            line-height: 1!important; 
            margin: 0 0px 25px; } 

  h3 { 
   font-size: 30px!important;  
   margin: 40px 0 -10px;  
   text-align: left; 
   background-color: red;} 

  .teal { 
     color: #519B96!important; }
```

```html
<h3 class="teal">«Les Lettres persanes» (1721)</h3> 
   <p class="p1">
     “Les Lettres persanes”, roman qu’il publie dans l’anonymat à Amsterdam 
      en 1721
</p>
```